# custom action fails to execute

Tags: installation, launch, advanced-installer

During the installation that I made I run in custom action file called ConfigurationUtility.exe witch should create a SQL database with some parameters. It should run some scripts in directory \scripts where the utility is copied. But I have this error in event log: "Action ConfigurationUtility.exe, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI4724.tmp, command: -dbname NewDB -username sa -password .....
I think it's happens because the installer trying to run it from C:\Windows\Installer\MSI4724.tmp but not from the Installation folder.

Setup package is built with Advanced Installer.

How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have not configured the custom action correctly.

If you want it to run some scripts from the installation folder where it is placed you should call the EXE using the custom action "**Launch installed file**". You should not launch it as an attached file custom action (only this type of custom actions get extracted as temp files and launched as in your example)

Also, since this is an EXE I recommend you give it full admin rights to run, otherwise the system might stop it from running. To do this configure the custom action to "**When the system is being modified**" and "**Run under the LocalSystem account with full privileges**", and make sure it is scheduled to run after "**Add Resources**" group (where Advanced Installer ads it by default)